# Finding a certain point in a data and similar data

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science, numerical-analysis

I am trying to find the point when the drastic decrease in the data points start (the point where it is circled). The problem is that the data is also fluctuating a little before the point as well, so I cannot say that when the difference is negative then it is that point. Also the rate of decrease is not higher that the rate of fluctuations before the point. There are different data sets with the similar pattern and I would like to script it in a way that it works for all of them.[image]

Unfortunately, I don't have a code sample to show here as I don't have an idea how to find that point.

Comment: You might work with filtering (e.g. in scipy) and differentiating (numpy diff) the data. Looking at the gradient you should be able to identify the kink. Maybe a code sample from you can point you to more specific help.

Comment: I don't have a code sample, since i don't have an idea how to get that.